# CMYK export illustrator to JPEG and/or PNG

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export, cmyk

I need to export my illustrator artwork to a JPEG or PNG.
I checked everywhere to see is my file was in CMYK and also my colors. Everything looks alright. But, when I export my file it seems that the colors are wrong.

Do you know where that can come from ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: PNG does **not** support CMYK color. It's an entirely inappropriate format if you need CMYK.

Comment: Thanks that was i thought... but i should not have this pb for a JPEG ?

Answer (score 2):

PNG doesn't support CMYK colour.

If you want to save a CMYK JPEG, it is possible.  In Illustrator hit File > Export, choose jpeg as the file format, and when the export dialog appears set the colour model to CMYK.

It's not advisable to save JPEGs in CMYK mode because not all web browsers or image viewers can display CMYK images properly.  So if you are thinking of using the image on a website, think again!

Answer (score -3):

Does it happen when you save PNG too ? Because whenever it happens with me with JPEGs I use PNGs and it works

Also make sure that the color profile is CMYK in the image export window

And check " assign profile " from Edit> and check if it's CMYK or not , and try disabling the color management

Hope it works!

Comment: Wellcome Lina Al Shura. This answer is wrong. One thing is that the png can embed a cmyk profile and one totally diferent is to save cmyk channels. It can not.